# Title isn't showing on 'teaser'

Tags: 7, nodes

I've configured my view to show only a teaser of the nodes it's loading, but for some reason, the title of the node just won't show up.

I've looked in my `node.tpl.php`  but as it turns out, this file isn't even used and my `template.tpl.php` only states this:

```
if ('teaser' == $vars['elements']['#view_mode']) {
  return;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?